# Latex table goes out of page border

Tags: tables, margins, border

I have the following table:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{\textbf{Economic school}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Drivers}}}                                                   \\ \hline
Classical                                               & Goverment interfers, market regulates itself                                                     \\ \hline
Keynesians                                              & Spending is low                                                                                  \\ \hline
New classical                                           & Exogenous shocks, large crisis                                                                   \\ \hline
Austrian                                                & Central banks intervent with monetary policies                                                   \\ \hline
Endogenous                                              & Innovation and new technology                                                                    \\ \hline
Others                                                  & Some examples are, political cycle, pork cycle, seasons, sun and moon phases or biological cycle \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Brief overview of all economic schools and their understanding of cyclical drivers.\cite{BormotovMichael2009}}
\label{table:economicSchools}   
\end{table}
```

However, it goes out of my page border, see here:

[image]

Any suggestions how to fix this?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: The following is a comment about the *economic content* of the tabular material, rather than any typesetting aspects: As a professional economist, I must say that the way the material is presented makes my stomach churn. Is the material given in your reference (BormotovMichael2009) really as simplistic and amateurish as the table suggests? I sure hope this isn't the case.

Comment: @Mico Thx for your answer! I really appreciate your comment about the material. Here is the link to the paper: http://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/19660/ .I would kindly ask you, by using this table I am trying to summarize the drivers for cycles for each economic school. What would you suggest to make better? Would also appreciate if you could send me a mail, regarding the material!

Comment: I've read the paper; it looks like your table is based on Table 6 of the paper you cite. My verdict: The paper's not very good, to put it charitably. (E.g., the six "schools of thought" appear out of nowhere, not having been introduced before they make their first appearance in the table.) A basic course in business cycle theory could last an entire semester -- it's *not* possible to give an adequate summary of the main results here. My advice would be to drop all references to "schools of thought", unless they really belong in your work. If you keep them, please portray them more accurately.

Comment: Does the answer below solve your question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are some options to improve this:

- Use a `p` columntype with some width specification for the simplest solution. This uses a `\parbox` and wraps the content at the box width. Alternatively use a `\newcolumntype` from `array` package (Please note that `p{0.8\linewidth}` is still too wide in this case)
- Package `tabularx` provides the automatic adaption of cell width of cells specified with `X` type.

I additionally applied the `booktabs` for a 'better' look of the table, but I would not use the vertical rules in the table, however.

---

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{0.8\linewidth}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{\textbf{Economic school}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Drivers}}}                                                   \tabularnewline \hline
Classical                                               & Goverment interfers, market regulates itself                                                     \tabularnewline \hline
Keynesians                                              & Spending is low                                                                                  \tabularnewline \hline
New classical                                           & Exogenous shocks, large crisis                                                                   \tabularnewline \hline
Austrian                                                & Central banks intervent with monetary policies                                                   \tabularnewline \hline
Endogenous                                              & Innovation and new technology                                                                    \tabularnewline \hline
Others                                                  & Some examples are, political cycle, pork cycle, seasons, sun and moon phases or biological cycle \tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Brief overview of all economic schools and their understanding of cyclical drivers.\cite{BormotovMichael2009}}
\label{table:economicSchools}   
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{\textbf{Economic school}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Drivers}}}                                                   \tabularnewline \hline
Classical                                               & Goverment interfers, market regulates itself                                                     \tabularnewline \hline
Keynesians                                              & Spending is low                                                                                  \tabularnewline \hline
New classical                                           & Exogenous shocks, large crisis                                                                   \tabularnewline \hline
Austrian                                                & Central banks intervent with monetary policies                                                   \tabularnewline \hline
Endogenous                                              & Innovation and new technology                                                                    \tabularnewline \hline
Others                                                  & Some examples are, political cycle, pork cycle, seasons, sun and moon phases or biological cycle \tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{tabularx-version: Brief overview of all economic schools and their understanding of cyclical drivers.\cite{BormotovMichael2009}}
\label{table:economicSchools2}   
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{\textbf{Economic school}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{\textbf{Drivers}}}                                                   \tabularnewline 
Classical                                               & Goverment interfers, market regulates itself                                                     \tabularnewline \midrule
Keynesians                                              & Spending is low                                                                                  \tabularnewline \midrule
New classical                                           & Exogenous shocks, large crisis                                                                   \tabularnewline \midrule
Austrian                                                & Central banks intervent with monetary policies                                                   \tabularnewline \midrule
Endogenous                                              & Innovation and new technology                                                                    \tabularnewline \midrule
Others                                                  & Some examples are, political cycle, pork cycle, seasons, sun and moon phases or biological cycle \tabularnewline \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{tabularx-version with booktabs: Brief overview of all economic schools and their understanding of cyclical drivers.\cite{BormotovMichael2009}}
\label{table:economicSchools3}   

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]