# Getting Missing number, treated as zero error when trying to fit table in the document

Tags: tables, luatex, lua, rendering

While trying to dynamically render a table, it gets out of the document generated and looks as follows:

[image]

To avoid this, I followed the steps mentioned in:

- [SO Post - 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245382/latex-table-goes-out-of-page-border), which uses `tabularx`
- [SO Post - 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121155/how-to-adjust-a-table-to-fit-on-page), which uses `adjustbox`

But for both the approaches tried, I get an error saying:

```
Missing number, treated as zero
```

I tried [reading about this error](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Missing_number,_treated_as_zero) but could not understand, as it does not throw any error when doing without `tabularx` or `adjustbox`.

I am rendering my table using `lualatex` code as shown below:

```
 tex.print("\string\\begin{tabularx}{"  .. col_schema ..  "}") 

 -- row / col rendering here

 tex.print("\string\\end{tabularx}")
```

The document is generated from the [JSON](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbe2bd65). I have shared JSON with the link for easier viewing : https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbe2bd65

What could I do to avoid this error?

Comment: I don't think that tabularx is the right solution, better calculate your width and use p{} columns in a normal tabular.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you show how?

Comment: do not use tabularx especially if you are trying to make it fast and you have lots of them, it resets each table multiple times guessing column widths. If you do you it you need to generate the right syntax as noted in the answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you suggest a better way with an answer?

Comment: @Amanda use `\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{4cm}p{3cm}}`  for some suitable column widths, it is your document I can't pick suitable widths

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, okay! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
tex.print("\string\\begin{tabularx}{"  .. col_schema ..  "}")
```

This generates TeX code like

```
\begin{tabularx}{ | l | l|}
```

which misses a parameter: The tabularx environment expects the total width as first parameter, like

```
\begin{tabularx}{5cm}{ | X | X|}
```

Also this uses `X`, a column type for automatically sized columns. This type is the main feature of tabularx, so if you do not want to use it for your table, a normal `tabular` is a better choice.

So there are two possible fixes: Decide for a width and pass it to tabularx, additionally replace at least one column by a `X` column or replace `tabularx` with `tabular`. With `tabular`, you do not need to pass a width, TeX automatically uses the natural width of your table.

Comment: Okay. Is there a way to auto-tune the `width` parameter? With 5cm, I get table that looks as https://ibb.co/Ld3SVsy

Comment: @Amanda As Ulrike Fischer mentioned, you shouldn't use tabularx if you do want to set the table width. If you do want to set the width, but do not want to write an explicit number, you can e.g. use `\linewidth` to set the width to the width of the current line.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: `tabularx` will only work correctly if one uses at least one `X` type column. In your answer, the table uses two `l` type columns instead.