# table does not fit in page?

Tags: tables

I have referred to some questions posted earlier about this same topic, namely [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245382/latex-table-goes-out-of-page-border) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794679/latex-table-too-wide-how-to-make-it-fit) for fitting a table into a page. The code is taken from a guide I found online.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}\centering
\ra{1.4}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}rrrrcrrrcrrr@{}}\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 8$} & \phantom{abc}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 16$} &
\phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 32$}\\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-8} \cmidrule{10-12}
& $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$ && $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$ && $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$\\ \midrule
$dir=1$\\
$c$ & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 && 0.3670 & 0.7187 & 3.1815 && -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\
$c$ & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384&& -9.0714& 297.0923& 46.2143&& 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
$c$ & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721&& 128.2265& -630.5455& -381.0930&& -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
$dir=0$\\
$c$ & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119&& 0.3593& -0.2755& 2.1764&& -1.2998& -3.8202& -1.2784\\
$c$ & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591&& -30.7381& -9.5952& -3.0000&& -11.1631& -5.7108& -15.6728\\
$c$ & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351&& 100.2497& 141.2778& -259.7326&& 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]
(ignore the red circle)

I tried applying the solutions proposed in the above links to the current example:

- `p{width}` as in `\begin{tabular}{@{}rrrrcrrrcrrr@{}p{0.8\textwidth}}`
- `tabularx` environment as in `\begin{tabularx}{@{}rrrrcrrrcrrrX@{}}`
- `tabular*` environment as in `\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{@{}rrrrcrrrcrrrX@{}}`

**Edit** I am using a simple `article` class with no packages other than `booktabs`.

But they did not work? Any thoughts ?

Comment: Please make your code compile compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. How to make a table fit into the available space depending depends on how much space there is. If you use the geometry package, please include the corresponding setting into your MWE as well.

Comment: I'd start by getting rid of the empty columns between the t=2 and t=0 columns in order to save quite some space.

Comment: Additionally, you could use \multicolumn{5} {@{}l}{dir=1} in the first column to save even more space.

Comment: @leandriis I suppose so but the guide that I found purposefully introduces these spaces to emphasize on the division between the groupings on the topmost row.

Comment: If your table still does not fit, you could try a smaller font size and additionally reduce the value of tabcolsep. Alternatively, and especially if your table still does not fit, you could rotate it to a landscape orientation.

Comment: I definitely get that you want to group the columns in groups of 3, but for this, you don't really need an empty column, especially not, if your table is that wide. Instead, try with \midrule(lr){...} instead of \midrule{} and your groups of columns will still be visible.

Comment: How wide is the textblock? Any chance you could it increase it from its default? Alternatively, is rendering the table in landscape mode an option you can contemplate?

Comment: @Mico Unfortunately I am not familiar with either textblock or rendering tables in landscape mode.

Comment: @FirstUser - The text block of a printed page is surrounded by the margins. The width of the text block is the width of the physical page minus the widths of the left-hand-side and right-hand-side margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're willing and able to either enlarge the width of the textblock or choose a very small font size, I think your best option is to typeset the table in landscape mode, on a page by itself.

The following code achieves that by employing a `sidewaystable` environment. I would also like to suggest that you (a) employ an `array` environment intead of a `tabular` environment (since most of the material is math-y) and (b) load the `siunitx` package and employ its `S` column type to align the numbers in the numerical columns on their decimal markers. I would also omit the all-blank columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs} % \toprule, \midrule, \cmidrule, \bottomrule, \addlinespace 
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' environment
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable} 
\ra{1.1} % 1.4 seems excessive
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{} l *{9}{S[table-format=-3.4]} @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{w=8} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{w=16} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{w=32}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
& {t=0} & {t=1} & {t=2} & {t=0} & {t=1} & {t=2} & {t=0} & {t=1} & {t=2} \\ 
\midrule
\mbox{dir}=1\\
c & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 & 0.3670 & 0.7187 & 3.1815 & -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\
c & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384& -9.0714& 297.0923& 46.2143& 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
c & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721& 128.2265& -630.5455& -381.0930& -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\
\addlinespace
\mbox{dir}=0\\
c & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119& 0.3593& -0.2755& 2.1764& -1.2998& -3.8202& -1.2784\\
c & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591& -30.7381& -9.5952& -3.0000& -11.1631& -5.7108& -15.6728\\
c & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351& 100.2497& 141.2778& -259.7326& 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\caption{Caption}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```